# How to avoid mesh anomalies after Knife Project

Tags: modeling, artifacts

Using Knife Project to have some windows and doors in an aircraft fuselage, however the cut produces these anomalies around the window corners, where the triangulation is, that I cannot find a way to avoid or remove. Is there any way to get rid of these or at least have it less visible? Thanks.

[image: Anomalies where the triangulation is around the edges of the windows]

[image]

Comment: About the "why", some explanations here. But for practical case, you should upload your file (or the needed part of it), so that we can help you to find a solution. Please use this link: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @lemon I think you missed a link in your comment.

Comment: @mrborzoo To avoid "mesh anomalies" use a proper modeling technique instead. Knife project is a "lazy" method of modelling, it will inevitably create bad topology and issues.

Comment: In the comment above, I missed to add this link http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74656/cant-disolve-edge-and-faces/74660#74660 (thanks @DuarteFarrajotaRamos)

Comment: This can help also as "corrective" approach http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75858/how-do-i-prevent-overhangs-when-using-subdivision-modifier/75871#75871. But as said by @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, knife or boolean operations are some kind of lazy method (at least in Blender), so better topology is needed here (for instance, look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA)

Comment: Added the blend file. Regarding topology, I can't have a complex mesh since this is for the FOSS FlightGear simulator, so I suppose it will be very difficult to have only quads and keep it light.

Comment: @mrborzoo... ok for the file, but do you have to model before the knife cut? Because remaking it from what is in your file does not lead to the same result...